# How do I assemble and link a 64-bit gas syntax assembly file?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

Recently I have tried to learn GAS syntax. When I try to use gcc to compile/assemble and link my GAS source file I encounter an error: `undefined reference to 'WinMain'`. The command I am using is: `gcc -m64 -Wl,-e_start hello.S`. Here is my source file:

```
.section    .data

msg:        .ascii  "Hello, world!\n"
handle:     .byte   0
written:    .byte   0

.section        .text

.global _start

_start:

# GetStdHandle(-11)
pushq   $-11
call    GetStdHandle
movq    %rax, (handle)

# WriteConsoleA(*handle, msg, 13, written, 0)
pushq   $0
pushq   written
pushq   $13
pushq   msg
pushq   (handle)
call    WriteConsoleA

# ExitProcess(0)
pushq   $0
call    ExitProcess
```

Comment: Try `gcc -m64 -Wl,-e_start -nostdlib hello.S -lkernel32`

Comment: *"Recently I have tried to learn GAS syntax."* Why? Assemblers that use standard Intel syntax are free (as in beer and as in speech). There's no real reason to learn the Gnu syntax.

Comment: Memory variables handle: and written: should be dword, not byte. 
Size of msg: is 14 bytes, not $13.
Win32API functions should be explicitly declared as external or imported. They expect all parameters be dword, you should push dwords instead of qwords in all your pushes.
BTW you are creating 32bit Windows console application. 64bit programs use quite different calling convention.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I tried using that command @Jester suggested and it assembled/linked the file with no complaints. However, the program does not print hello world. Upon reading vitsoft's comment I can see that I have been doing this wrong. I will do further reading in trying to understand assembly.

Comment: @CodyGray as you are probably aware, GAS can do intel syntax. As for "standard intel syntax", there is no such thing unfortunately.

Comment: There *is* a standard, it is the one first documented by Intel and parsed by their original assembler (Intel ASM86 Macro Assembler). MASM matches this syntax almost exactly, except for the more advanced features. Now, naturally, [like all standards](https://xkcd.com/927/), we have plenty to choose from, but all Intel syntaxes are essentially the same, with only superficial differences (e.g., "Do I use `PTR` or not use `PTR`?"). Yes, GAS can handle Intel syntax. `-masm=intel` is the ticket. Still, it has plenty of other quirks that make it not an especially compelling general-purpose assembler.